# setting value of id attribute as variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

How to add id attribute of an element in HTML as a variable which is declared above in javascript.

**jQuery**

```
var table_row = $('table').find('tr#'+pid);  
var name = table_row.find('td:nth-child(1)').html();  
table_row.find('td:nth-child(6)').html('<button  type="button" id="what to write here" class ="save_db")>save</button> ');
```

I want to set id as name.

Thanks

Comment: Not able to get you. Please explain.

Comment: Not able to get you. Please explain.

Comment: (As per my understanding) He wants to set id dynamically by using javascript varibale. Please check 'what to write here' text in his code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using simple string concatenation as follows:

```
var table_row = $('table').find('tr#'+pid);  
var name = table_row.find('td:nth-child(1)').html();  
table_row.find('td:nth-child(6)')
  .html('<button  type="button" id="'+name+'" class ="save_db">save</button> ');
```

*PS: Also note that your markup contained a seemingly unnecessary `closing brace` after `class` attribute. I've removed it in my code.*

Answer (score 0):

So you just want a variable inserted into the html string?

```
table_row.find('td:nth-child(6)').html`(
    '<button  type="button" id="' + name + '" class ="save_db">save</button> '
)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate `name` variable to the appending string as `ID`.

```
table_row.find('td:nth-child(6)').html('<button  type="button" id="'+ name + '" 
class ="save_db")>save</button>');
```

Comment: Add single quote before  `id="`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code:

```
table_row.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.
Let me know if i am not understand your question.

```
var id = "btn1";
var table_row = $('table').find('tr#'+pid);  
var name = table_row.find('td:nth-child(1)').html();  
table_row.find('td:nth-child(6)').html('<button  type="button" id="'+id+'" class ="save_db")>save</button> ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Try using this:

```
<button type="button" id='"+name+"' class= "save_db">
```